# Custom Cursor flickers to default before moving

Tags: c#, wpf, flicker, custom-cursor

I am doing a WPF application, and I am trying to change the  default mouse cursor to one I made. I have the .cur file and everything works perfectly until I show a pop-up window, the mouse reverts to the default again before moving. Once you move the mouse the custom cursor returns.

I tried using the cursor by path(absolute and relative) and stream, putting the cursor as resource, embedded resource and/or content. And I also tried calling it from the app.xaml.cs, mainWindow.xaml.cs etc... The thing is that, no matter, where I put it, it doesn't take away the flicker.

Here is some of my code for loading the cursor:

```
    System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo sri = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Kulamity;component/media/mouseCursor.cur", UriKind.Relative));
    System.Windows.Input.Cursor customCursor = new System.Windows.Input.Cursor(sri.Stream);
    this.Cursor = customCursor;
```

And:

```
        var fullPath2 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("../../mouseCursor3.cur");
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = new Cursor(fullPath2);
```

What can I do to solve this issue? What could be the issue?

Comment: I should also mention that my app uses the MVC model.